# Windows form application using C++ in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have to do a project in windows form application in visual c++ 2008.I have to write codings in c++ in .h files.Can anyone tell me which resource helpful to learn more about windows form application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these tutorials:

[How to: Create a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235634%28VS.80%29.aspx)

If you are just looking for a tutorial to create a Windows application using c++ then see this:

[Windows API Tutorial](http://www.relisoft.com/win32/index.htm)

And a comprehensive tutorial on: [Win32 Programming](http://www.functionx.com/win32/)

Comment: Thanks very much.The msdn website that you mentioned easy to learn windows form application.

Comment: @user519675: If you find the answer useful, you might want to accept or up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find [theForger's Win32 API tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) simple to follow (with downloadable code), and its made specifically with visual studio in mind (iirc it doesn't *not* use MFC or the design mode, as its based off express edition features of VS).